# Extract value - Tree-Sort-Algorithm

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I would like to implement a method, which returns me the value of each node (or Knoten) one after another. The "going-through()"-Method below lets us explore the whole tree - but can I return the value of each node? Example: I call going-through()-method in a loop. First iteration I'll get the smallest value out of the tree, second iteration the next one, etc.

Tree-Sort-Class

```
public class Suchbaum {

    Knoten knoten;


    Suchbaum(int wert) {
        knoten = new Knoten(wert);
    }



    public Knoten insert(Knoten knoten, int wert) {

        if (knoten == null) {
            return new Knoten(wert);
        }

        if (wert< knoten.wert) {
            knoten.links = insert(knoten.links, wert);
        } else if (wert > knoten.wert) {
            knoten.rechts = insert(knoten.rechts, wert);
        }

        return knoten;
    }



    public void going_through(Knoten knoten) {

        if (knoten != null) {

            going_through(knoten.rechts);

            going_through(knoten.links);
        }
    }

}
```

Node/Knoten-Class

```
public class Knoten {

    int wert;
    Knoten rechts;
    Knoten links;


    Knoten(int wert){

        this.wert = wert;
        rechts = null;
        links = null;

    }

}
```